# Integration with switch of differential

Tags: integration

I am looking to solve integral with form

$$\int_a^b av\, dt$$

where $a=\frac{dv}{dt}$ is acceleration and $v=\frac{ds}{dt}$ is speed. Is following solution correct?

$$\int_a^b av\,dt=\int_a^b \frac{dv}{dt}\frac{ds}{dt}\,dt=\int_a^b v \, dv = \frac{v(b)^2-v(a)^2}{2}$$

I have doubts since $v$ is a really function of time and is not necessarily monotonic as I would intuitively expect it to be.

Thank you

Comment: It is right. The more formal way: You have $a(t) = v'(t)$. Just integrate by parts.

Comment: No, don't integrate by parts @user251257... $v'(t) v(t)$ is directly the derivative of $(v(t))^2/2$!

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: OP obviously didn't see that. So, I just propose a more mechanic way :)

Comment: This is not just OK but a very nice way to do the integral.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I have actually synthesized this specific example to illustrate the question whether the used method is valid .. should have noticed the per-partes solution and give better example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is correct. Another way to see this is to compute $$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{v^2}{2} = v \frac{d}{dt}v = va$$